# Compare elements in two list and add different ones

Tags: list, scheme, racket, sublist

My problem is that. I have a sublist (slst1) that contains random elements from another list (lst). Then, I need to create another one (slst2) that contains the elements of lst not in slst1, but, when I compare them, the result is not what I'm expected.

A call will be:

```
(split 0.3 lst)
```

where '0.3' it's a proportion of list I want to take.

lst contains:

```
((a11 a12 a13 a14)(a21 a22 a32 a42) (a31 a32 a33 a34))
```

and, for example, slst1 contains:

```
((a21 a22 a23 a24))
```

then, slst2 should contain:

```
((a11 a12 a13 a14) (a31 a32 a33 a34))
```

but, with my code, slst2 contains always the same items that lst, not only the different ones.

This is my code:

```
(define (split proportion lst)
(let((ne (* proportion (length lst)))(slst1 '())(slst2 '()))
;Calculate first sublist
(when (> ne 0)
  (for ([i (inexact->exact ne)])
    (if (null? lst)
       (set! slst1 (list-ref lst (random (length lst))))
       (set! slst1 (list lst (list-ref lst (random (length lst)))))))
 ;Try to calculate second sublist 
   (for ([i (length lst)]
     #:when (not(member (list-ref lst i) slst1)))
  (set! slst2 (list slst2 (list-ref lst i)))
     )
 slst2)))
```

I'm a noobie in Racket, so any advice will be perfect. Thank you for reading/asking.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you call `split`, the result you get, and the expected result?

Comment: The code you've posted for `split` isn't legal ­— it doesn't compile because parentheses are missing.

Comment: Joshua Taylor, I have to say that, for me, in Dr. Racket, it's legal. So, take care with the copy-paste.

uselpa: In the morning I put an example, a call and the result expected. Sorry for the bad question. It's my first one ^^''

Comment: No Pedro, your code does not compile, is incomplete (take-random is missing) and poorly indented (DrRacket can do this for you automatically), @JoshuaTaylor is correct about this.

Comment: @PedroL. You can count the parentheses manually if you have to: in `(let ((ne (* proportion (length lst)))(slst1 '())(slst2 '())
(when (> ne 0)` the variable binding for `slst2` is `(slst2 '())`.  If there's another right paren after that, it would close the list of variables for `let`.  There's _not_ though, so `(when (> ne 0) ...` is the beginning of another variable which doesn't seem like what you'd want.

Comment: Did you cut some code out and replace it with `;Calculate first sublist` ?  Please note that questions on StackOverflow get closed for reasons like "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself."  It is important that you provide code that can be compiled and run (when the problem is in code that produces unexpected or incorrect results).

Comment: I apologies for this. Yep, a ) was missing. And yes, I forgot that code for (take-random) is mine, and not a Racket function. So sorry for that, @JoshuaTaylor and uselpa. For next questions I make sure everything is how you said right now. The question is answered anyway. Thank you for help and comments.

Comment: @PedroL. Even though the question is answered _for you_, it's still worth posting a complete version of the code so that anyone else who comes to this question in the future can benefit more from it. Another reason that questions get closed/deleted from StackOverflow is that they aren't considered likely to be helpful to future users.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've changed the code when I read your suggestion, an hour ago. I put a code that doesn't need (take-random) and keep the same error for I made this question. So, no problem now and no risk for get closed/deleted (except the -2 in the question). Thank you for the advices. I take care next time I have to ask for something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this will do:

```
(define (split proportion lst)
  (define le (length lst))
  (define slst1 
    (for/list ([i (inexact->exact (round (* proportion le)))]) 
      (list-ref lst (random le))))
  (define slst2 
    (for/list ([e (in-list lst)] #:unless (member e slst1)) 
      e))
  (values slst1 slst2))
```

then

```
(split 0.5 '((a11 a12 a13 a14)(a21 a22 a32 a42) (a31 a32 a33 a34) (a41 a42 a43 a44)))
=> '((a11 a12 a13 a14) (a21 a22 a32 a42))
   '((a31 a32 a33 a34) (a41 a42 a43 a44))
```

Note that slst1 can contain the same member more than once, so (length slst1) + (length slst2) can be larger than (length lst). Also, you can get weird results if members appear more than once in the initial list.

If you want to avoid this, you could go for the following:

```
(define (split prop lst)
  (for/fold ((s1 '()) (s2 lst)) ([i (inexact->exact (round (* (length lst) prop)))])
    (define rn (random (length s2)))
    (values 
     (cons (list-ref s2 rn) s1)
     (append (take s2 rn) (drop s2 (add1 rn))))))
```

s1 gets initialised to null, s2 to lst. Whenever we add an element to s1 we take it away from s2.

Comment: What do you mean by "quit the -1"?

Comment: I edit my question . This works, but I need to mantein the function (take-random lst). Anyway, I think I can adapt it. Any other advice? Why do you use for/fold instead only for? What's the different?

Comment: So what is your definition of take-random? Can you post the code?

Comment: Re: `for/fold` - have you used the excellent Racket docs? In the editor, put your cursor on for/fold and press F1. There's another example there that should make it clearer.